# iOS UI elements won't update while in the method called

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm doing a pretty simple iOS/ObjC program. Click a button, it's loops thru a for..next and displays counters and pics.

```
for (int i=0; i <= numberOfExercises; i++) {
    exerciseName = [exercises objectAtIndex:j][0];
    [self.lastLabel setText:exerciseName];
    [self.lastLabel setNeedsDisplay];
    usleep(1000000);
    NSLog(@"Count: %d Name:%@", i, exerciseName);
}
```

However, it's not updating the actual textfield on the screen.

I've tried everything I know of and there's just something I can't see.

```
(IBAction)btnExerciseClicked:(id)sender { 
    for (int i=0; i <= numberOfExercises; i++) {
        exerciseName = [exercises objectAtIndex:j][0]; 
        exerciseImageName = [exercises objectAtIndex:j][1];
        exerciseImageName = [exerciseImageName stringByAppendingString:@".jpg"];
        self.exerciseImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:exerciseImageName];
        [self.ExerciseName setText:exerciseName];
        [self.ExerciseName setNeedsDisplay];
        [self.exerciseImage setNeedsDisplay];
    }
```

**I've put the block in there:**

```
double delayInSeconds = 0.1;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds *     NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    NSLog(@"inside the block");
    [self.ExerciseName setText:exerciseName];
    [self.ExerciseName setNeedsDisplay];
    [self.exerciseImage setNeedsDisplay];
});
```

**And I've done a direct assign before the loop starts:**

```
exerciseName = [exercises objectAtIndex:5][0];
[self.ExerciseName setText:exerciseName];
[self.ExerciseName setNeedsDisplay];
NSLog(@"Name: %@", self.ExerciseName.text);
```

**I've even written a separate method for it:**

```
-(void) myCycleDisplay: (NSString *) imageName
    nameOfExercise: (NSString *) exerciseName
         voiceOver: (BOOL) useVoiceOver
         countDown: (BOOL) useCountDown
              beep: (BOOL) useBeep{

[self.ExerciseName setText:exerciseName];
[self.ExerciseName setNeedsDisplay];
self.exerciseImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
}
```

And after all that, STILL no display until AFTER the method is done. Put in a delay: usleep(1000000);

I've confirmed that the data is in the element. I've setup the element in code and in IB.

The app is pretty simple, a button is pressed on the screen, data is loaded, an array is walked and display items are updated based on elements in the array.

The data is in the textfield, this has been confirmed. It even display them, but only after the method is exited.

Once the method is exited, the text/pic are displayed properly.

So, as a test, I made the for..next loop run twice and clicked the button over and over. Sure enough it displayed properly AFTER leaving the method.

I can't get it to update the display while IN the method. (this also includes the slider).

Why do I have to exit a method to get the display to update?

Comment: I've added a new viewcontroller and moved all the UI elements to it, still they will not update.

Comment: What is the deep sense to overwrite the values of `ExerciseName` and `exerciseImage`  in each loop? And actually you don't need the `setNeedsDisplay` lines. You have only to take care that all UI updates are performed on the main thread.

Comment: What actually you want to do here ? from array you want last object data fill in textfield and image or something else you need to try here ?

Comment: `setNeedsDisplay` sets a flag that is frequently checked and triggers updating the view than. You are working on a serial (non concurrent) queue, the main queue. So the method that is checking the flag can not run before your function finished.

Comment: @user1085596 Will you send me demo at jiten.benzatine@gmail.com, If you dont mind ?  I will see it and give you a proper solution of it

Comment: It's a little hard to understand what you are trying to achieve there and I apologize if my guess is incorrect. Here's my theory: you are trying to update UI from within a method in the main queue and want the results to be displayed while the method is still executing. If that is the case, your method blocks the main queue and, even if you add some blocks to the main queue, they will not be executed before the current method execution ends. If my guess is correct, would you be so kind as to explain what you are trying to do so that we can help you?

Comment: @Baglan you are correct.  Think of a timer and display.  You go thru the array and update the UI.  The problem is that the UI doesn't update until after you leave the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest solution to your problem is to dump the whole for-loop into another queue.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    for (int i=0; i <= numberOfExercises; i++) {
        NSString *exerciseName = [exercises objectAtIndex:i][0];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.lastLabel setText:exerciseName];
            [self.lastLabel setNeedsDisplay];
        });
        usleep(1000000);
        NSLog(@"Count: %d Name:%@", i, exerciseName);
    }
});
```

There are three additional changes.

1. Changed `[exercises objectAtIndex:j]` to `[exercises objectAtIndex:i]`

   I think this was a mistake on your part
2. Made `exerciseName` local to the block.

   I could have made the declaration of `exerciseName` `__block`, but it's easier to just make the whole thing local.
3. Wrapped setting the label in `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ … });`

   UI updates must be made on the main queue.

---

Note, this is a **bad** solution. You should rethink your approach entirely. I would move this logic into it's own separate class, then use notifications to get the UI to update.

Comment: This worked for the UIText but not the slider or imageview.  I put these in a different VC, but need to make call from the calling VC for the UI updates.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `usleep(1000000)` you are **blocking the main queue**. UI updates happen on the main queue, but you're blocking that queue, so they don't happen. Also, UI updates in general don't happen until you finish the current pass through the event loop-- from the user tapping your button, through your method doing whatever it needs to do, continuing until **your method finishes**. Then UIKit updates the UI. You need to let your method finish because that's how UIKit works.

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do. If you want to update your UI at intervals, look into `NSTimer`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood the problem well enough to give a relevant answer and I apologize if I didn't. Here's how I see it:

- There is a set of exercises that have to be done one after another;
- Exercises take certain amount of time;
- The name of the exercise and a relevant image are displayed when exercise starts.

The current implementation does precisely that: display is updated and the system sleeps for a certain amount of time before updating the display again.

The problem with that approach is that UIKit frameworks that is commonly used when doing interactive things on iOS devices is what could be called *"indirect"*. For instance, when *.text* property of a label is updated, text is not drawn, instead, the system is notified that display should be updated. UIKit periodically checks whether updates are requested and if they are, the display is redrawn.

All of this is done on the "main queue" by sequentially executing blocks of code added to it (as a side note, this is to unlike the way Javascript work in a browser). This means that as long as some block of code is executed, everything else of the main queue will not be and the app will stop being interactive and updating display. Thus, the way to use UIKit is by quickly notifying it of necessary changes and finishing the function. Consequently, one never does long calculations or *"sleeps"* on on the main queue.

In context of this question, this leaves a problem of timed updates: we want to update the UI after some time has expired. There are 2 solution that come to mind:

1. The "typical" one would to be use the NSTimer class;
2. If constant updates to the UI are necessary, there is a CADisplayLink class and a convenient [UIScreen displayLinkWithTarget:selector:] method to create one on, say, [UIScreen mainScreen]. What it does is, it calls the *selector* in time for screen updates (currently, that's about 60 times per second but you can configure it to be called less frequently). It is ideal for things like count-down timers and frequently updating UI elements such as progress bars.

(I've switched to Swift and the latest API so the method names might not be exactly right in Objective-C).

Please let me know if I misunderstood the question or if you need sample code or further clarification.

Good luck!